# Linkedin API - get number of connections

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I can successfully download LinkedIn connections, but now I am trying to get one extra object for the user - their number of connections.  The documentation seems to suggest that I need "total" or "_total" but I have tried all combinations with no success.  All I get is "undefined".  Here's the code with examples of what I'm trying to get the total count:

```
    IN.API.Connections("me")
    .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "mainAddress", "dateOfBirth", "phoneNumbers", "positions", "pictureUrl"])
    .params({"count":500})
    .error(displayError)
    .result(function(result) {

        document.write("1 ", result.values._total, "<br>");
        document.write("2 ", result.values.total, "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned JSON is of the format:

```
{
    "_count": #,
    "_start": #,
    "_total": #,
    "values": [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

So you would access the total number of connections returned via `result._total`.